# Query From Join table With Extra column for Many-to-Many relationship [ASP.NET MVC]

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database

How can i query to Access Extra fields(**Batch**,**Part**) in my Association table (**StaffCourses**) for many-to-many relationship in ASP.Net MVC.

Edited: I have `Staff_Id` in hand. so how to query through `Staff_Id` .
[image].

Comment: `var data = _context.Courses.Include(p => p.StaffCourses).ToList();`

Comment: @CristianSzpisjak i have `Staff_Id` in hand. so i want to query through `staff_Id` .

Comment: are you using EF?

Comment: yes EF, Database First approach

Comment: Add in your DbContext a reference to Staff like `public virtual DbSet<Staff> Staff { get; set; }`. Then you can use `var data = _context.Staff.Include(p => p.StaffCourses).ToList();`